# typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return false positive for stencils JSX

Tags: typescript, eslint, stenciljs

I am using some recommended linter configs and one of them configures:

```
'@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return': 'error',
```

which leads to errors in all my stencil components at the return statement:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Host>
        </Host>
    );
}
```

The whole return part is underlined red and the error states:

> 24:9  error  Unsafe return of an `any` typed value @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return

Additionally, I observed something odd: when I remove `"jsxFactory": "h"` from my tsconfig, the error disappears.

Before I disable the rule or ad a type to the return statement, I would like to understand what's going on here, can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the missing return type, try to add :JSX.Element after render() and import the type from @stencil/core